# how use href attrib scriptlet on javascritp to dynamically load a page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, location-href

Hi I'm trying to make a code to open a url dynamically, first I try from HTML using this:

```
var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.p || "Web";
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate();
} 

<a href="<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=Alumno' ?>" Id="myA">Página Alumno</a>
```

and works fine, but I need that action after make click on a button element so I code this in my script:

```
document.location.href = document.getElementById("myA").href;
```

but this give me an error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwLXIef95aeUGyRFiP3lH_-Oac6ByXem17VjnPjdXpN/dev?p=indEntregas'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

What its wrong with this, how I can make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't answer a lot of questions about this issue I find a solution for the error message...

To see the pages opened without conflict, I set the target option of the page to open on "_blank", also set the a element as follow on script:

```
function abrirUrl(url) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.href = url;
        a.click();

    }

    var url = "<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=Alumno' ?>";
```

Then on button_click:

```
function abrirInicio(){
    abrirUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode) and this will allow any site to iframe your web app.

```
 output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Comment: thank you, that will be after return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate() ??? in that case doesn't work